# firefox extension: tab's body is loaded

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

How can bind onload event on "body" element of second tab in Firefox extension?
I can't use window.onload 'cause it binds on current tab.
So how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I didn't read the part about opening a new tab.
We're doing it with this code in the [SendToPhone](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxtophone/) extension:

```
var tab = gBrowser.addTab(url);
var c2pTab = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(tab);
//Add listener 
c2pTab.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // do your stuf
}, true);
```

For reference, the initial answer proposed a generic "detect page load":
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load

Comment: It seems to me that you've understood me wrong. I have many code in my extension which do something, then my extension click on link and it causes new tab. How can I bind on event on 2nd tab loading?

Comment: Sorry, these days I'm not thinking right due to a little cold. The new answer should be better (I hope)